# Trying to install postgresql16-client on an Alpine Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, postgresql, alpine-linux

I'm trying to create a Docker container with postgresql16-client but i'm getting an error saying that the package does not exist.

I'm going to also install dotnet 8 on this container in order to run an API, the postgresql16-client i will be using to pg_dump a database

[image: Image with Dockerfile and error]

I have no clue which repositories I have to import, how do you know which repositories you need in Linux in order to install a program?

I found this site but I don't know how to fetch this repository https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/postgresql16-client

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your posted image, you are using alpine v3.15 which does not include `postgresql16-client`.

According to the link you posted, you would need to use either Alpine Edge or Alpine v3.19 for `postgresql16-client` to be available in the package repositories.

The only [Alpine version with `dotnet8-*` packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=dotnet*&branch=edge) right now is Alpine Edge, so you would need to use that version for your Docker containers.

A note if you are not aware:  [Alpine Edge is the current development tree of Alpine Linux used mainly for testing](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Repositories#Edge) and may not be as stable as a released version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i ended up figuring this out on my own yesterday but your answer is spot on, my issue was the version of Alpine, i'm now using 3.19 and i was able to install dotnet 8 in 3.19